# Load images in listview only when they are about to display

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, scroll, metadata

I am working on making a music player and what i have done so far is that I created a song list in listview with their thumbnail images using metadata files. 
Now when i scroll my list it lags, that might be because of the image loading.
I referred to Google Play Music App and what they have done is that they fetch album art at the time of scrolling so scrolling is smooth.
Is there any way to implement that kind of functionality?

Comment: In your listview you may asynchronously load your image to views. see http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use lazy loading of images, so images will be downloaded in background.

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap> {

    ImageView imageView = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
        this.imageView = imageViews[0];
        return download_Image((String) imageView.getTag());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {
        try {
            URL ulrn = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) ulrn.openConnection();

            InputStream iS = con.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iS);
            return bmp;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Make a call to this class in your adapter getview

```
imgThumbnail.setTag(<your image url>);
new DownloadImage().execute(imgThumbnail);
```

Comment: I dont want to fetch images from url. i want them from uri. what is the way? is imgThumbnail an ImageView?

Comment: That's the async task and imgthumbnail is a imageview. You can modify the async task to fit your requirement. If you need an example, give me a sample uri